# How to check if in database column row is set to 1

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm trying to make admin.php where only administrator can access that page. So all users in database have privileges set by 0 default. If user has 1 that means he should be able to see admin.php page. How do I write code to check if person has 1 in his previleges?

```
          if ( $privileges ){
          echo
          '<div class="info">
          You are not administrator!
          </div>';
      }
```

So I'm asking in the first line of code, what should I write to check in database if user administrator or not.

Comment: `Select * From Table Where User = 'X' and privileges = 1`...?

Comment: Thanks for fast answer, but I asked something else. Fx if { this person doesnt has privileges set by 1 then echo" you cannot access that page" elseif { welcome

Comment: Please include the code you have tried so far.

Comment: well the query suggested above is the first part of the puzzle. Run the query from PHP passing in the username/ID of the current user. Return the result of the query to your PHP application. Read the result into a variable and use an if statement to check the value of the variable and act appropriately. Which part of that are you stuck with? You can easily google how to run queries from PHP, and the rest is really quite trivial logic e.g. `if($row["privileges"] === 1) { //show the page } else { //redirect somewhere else and kill this script }`.

Comment: That helped me ADyson. Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

With simple Mysqli:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,`SELECT `privileges` FROM (your tablename) WHERE user = (the logged in user) AND privileges = "1");
```

Then to show the page:

```
while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    if(row['privileges'] === "1"){
    //show page
    }else{
    //do not show page
    }
}
```